# css adding padding to a child in a flex-1 parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following html/css is simply a wrapper container, a header, and a main flex-1 div wherein lives a sidebar that either has 0 width or 96 width depending on user click.

Because the sidebar is constantly changing and I wanted the rest of space to adjust accordingly, I set the rest as "flex-1 bg-black" (id="weird-dive").

However, I'm running into an issue where I want one of the children of the "flex-1 bg-black" div to have padding. Now the padding is causing not just the weird-div to overflow but also the main-container.

```
<div id="main-container" className="flex min-h-screen flex-col bg-background">
  <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 w-full border-b border-border/40 bg-background/95 backdrop-blur supports-[backdrop-filter]:bg-background/60">
  </header>
  <div className=" bg-yellow-300 flex flex-1">
    <div id="side-bar"
      className={`${
        sidebarDisplay ? "w-96" : "w-0"
      } bg-rose-300 transition-width duration-500 ease-in-out`}
    > // Sidebar
      <div className="relative h-full">
        <div className="w-4 absolute top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 -right-[21.8px] -rotate-90">
          <Button
            onClick={handleSetSidebarDisplay}
            className="rounded-t-none px-5 py-0 h-7 w-32 z-10 cursor-pointer"
          >
            My tasks
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="weird-div" className="flex-1 bg-black overflow-y-scroll"> 
      <div className="pt-20"> // this overflows main-container
        {dummyData.map((task, index) => {
          const direction =
            index % 2 === 0 || index === 0
              ? "justify-start"
              : "justify-end";

          return (
            <div className="flex justify-center items-center w-full bg-black">
              <Checkpoint direction={direction} task={task} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried giving it an overflow-y-scroll but the main container is still overflowing as well. UI isn't my strong suit so if anyone can point out my noob mistakes, would greatly appreciate.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` to make flex elements to take padding and borders into account. Also, maybe `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink` might help you with adjusting the elements dynamically. Since it changes on user click.